# formatting a pandas dataframe with multiple rows as ids

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project where I am converting tables from filemaker to airtable.  Normally this would be straightforward, however, I have a lot of Unicode characters that are not transferring properly, which requires me to go and manually change those entries.

*an example of a table that I am converting

```
unique id artifact rec'd before treatment biography ...
0         blanket  12/1  yes              lorem ipsum
1         blanket  12/1  yes              lorem ipsum
2         blanket  12/1  yes              lorem ipsum
3         blanket  12/1  yes              lorem ipsum
4         blanket  12/1  yes              lorem ipsum
```

What I am doing is taking the csv outputs from both files and then doing a comparison against them, and creating a new file from the results.  This gives me all the differences.  Currently, the output looks something like this file:

```
0   1          2    3    4    5       6           7           8
694 label     lorem  
675 biography henry  675 text  lorem
708 text      foo    708 label bar    708         description ipsum
```

What I would like is to be able to format this so that instead of 29+ columns wide it would be taller.

My idea output would like like this:

```
0   1          2  
694 label     Lorem 
675 biography henry 
675 text      ipsum
708 text      foo    
708 label     bar    
708 description ipsum
```

This should be a `pandas.melt` issue, but I am having difficulty figuring out how best to condense the rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated, but some list comprehension based off of grouping and processing every three columns:

```
out = pd.concat([df[df.columns[i*3:i*3+3]].rename(columns={i*3:0, i*3+1:1, i*3+2:2})
                                          .dropna()
                 for i in range(len(df.columns)//3)], 
                 ignore_index=True)
print(out)

# Output:
       0            1      2
0  694.0        label  lorem
1  675.0    biography  henry
2  708.0         text    foo
3  675.0         text  lorem
4  708.0        label    bar
5  708.0  description  ipsum
```